# Library module doesn't include dependencies in Android

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, module

I am working on a `multi-module` project and this project should have a `Java Library` module called `test-shared` to provide common test classes. However, I am facing an issue in which my module doesn't recognize dependencies and I cannot write my classes.

Things have been done

1. Enable offline mode and disable again.
2. Delete `.gradle` folder and sync.
3. Googled identical issues.
4. Invalidate cache & restart.

As a result, I don't have a working project. Your help would be welcome.

> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.test:rules:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.1.0"
}

sourceCompatibility = "8"
targetCompatibility = "8"
```

> Example class

```
class Co {

    val a = LiveData<Co>()
    val b = Observer<Co>()
}
```

In this example, neither `LiveData` nor `Observer` are recognized. Could you please help me fix this weird issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is not the entirety of your library's gradle file, then you are missing the android plugins.

Please add the following at the top of your library's gradle file.

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
```

I will also recommend having a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Comment: Thanks for your reply Giorgos. Android library and Java library are not identical. In this case I want to add a Java module in my project. However, it doesn't include dependencies. I will just store classes for other modules. No more.

Comment: @nuhkoca Android libraries can have java modules where java modules cannot have android module dependencies. I will suggest you make the change and run the library to see that it will work.

Comment: Thanks for reply. May I ask that, I am unable to add any dependencies to my Java Library? You mean that? I don't want a library which has resources, manifests or something like that.

Comment: You cannot add Android dependencies to a Java library

Comment: @nuhkoca I still don't understand what you are trying to do. The dependencies you are trying to add "androidx.X.X:x.x.x" are obviously android ones. With a pure java library this is not possible. You would need to replace your "apply plugin" with the one posted in my answer. I recommend you reading the basic stuff before getting started.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous ahh ok, I got your point, thanks it is now resolved. Do you know what kind of dependencies can I add to Java Library?

Comment: Yes, you can add only pure java dependencies which do not have direct or transitive android dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your help!